# Segfault in getline

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, readline

The following code is supposed to read the file "rules.txt" and write it to a device line by line.
The flow should be:

1. Read line from rules.txt
2. Echo it to device

The following code always end in segfault because of readline and I have no idea why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
  

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

int main()
{
    char *line;
    size_t len = BUFFER_LENGTH;
    
    int fd = open("./rules.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1)
    { perror("open failed"); return 0; }

    FILE* fout = fopen("/sys/class/Rule_Table_Class/Rule_Table_Class_Rule_Table_Device/sysfs_att", "w+");

    if(fout == NULL)
    { close(fd); perror("fopen failed, log.txt is busy!"); return 0; }

    while (1) 
    {
        line = (char*) malloc(len*sizeof(char));
        
        if(line==NULL){
perror("malloc failed!"); return 0; 
}

        int bytesRead = getline(&line, &len, fd);
        
        if (bytesRead == -1) 
        {
            perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
            return errno;
        }

        sprintf(line,"%s","lala");
        printf("line = %s", line);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

I corrected the code and still get a segfault. Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
  

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    
   fp = fopen("./rules.txt", "r");


    if(fp  == NULL)
    { perror("open failed"); return 0; }

    FILE* fout = fopen("/sys/class/Rule_Table_Class/Rule_Table_Class_Rule_Table_Device/sysfs_att", "w+");

    if(fout == NULL)
    {  perror("fopen failed!"); return 0; }

    while (1) 
    {
        

        ssize_t bytesRead = getline(&line, &len, fp);
        
        if (bytesRead == -1) 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        printf("line = %s", line);
        fprintf(line,"%s",fout);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getline` takes a `FILE *`, not an `int` (file descriptor).

Comment: @Cheatah I didn't notice that I wrote "readline" instead of "getline" by mistake, thanks for pointing that out, I edited the title.

Comment: Your `fprintf` has the parameters in the wrong order: `fprintf(fout,"%s",line);` You should really enable compiler warnings and pay close attention to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the proper core `getline()` loop is

```c
 /* FILE     *in = fopen(..., "r"); */
    char   *line = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;

    while (1) {
        ssize_t  len = getline(&line, &size, in);
        if (len < 0)
            break;

        /* You have 'len' chars at 'line', with line[len] == '\0'. */
    }
```

so, it is not `getline()` that causes the segfault, it is your `fprintf(line, "%s", fout);` that should be either `fprintf(fout, "%s", line);` or just `fputs(line, fout);`, or `fwrite(line, 1, bytesRead, fout);` since the line can contain embedded NUL bytes that `fprintf()` and `fputs()` consider an end of string mark.

---

If we modify the code so that the source and target file names are taken as command-line arguments (with `-` denoting standard input or standard output), this is what I'd personally like to see:

```c
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0 */

/* This tells the GNU C library to expose POSIX features, including getline(). */
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *self = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", self);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s SOURCE TARGET\n", self);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This copies all content from SOURCE to TARGET, line by line.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Use '-' for standard input source or standard output target.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    const char *srcpath = argv[1];
    const char *dstpath = argv[2];

    /* If the path is "-", set it to NULL. */
    if (srcpath && !strcmp(srcpath, "-"))
        srcpath = NULL;
    if (dstpath && !strcmp(dstpath, "-"))
        dstpath = NULL;

    FILE *src, *dst;

    /* Open source for reading. If srcpath is NULL, use stdin. */
    if (srcpath) {
        src = fopen(srcpath, "r");
        if (!src) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", srcpath, strerror(errno));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        src = stdin;
    }

    /* Open target for writing. If dstpath is NULL, use stdout. */
    if (dstpath) {
        dst = fopen(dstpath, "w");
        if (!dst) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", dstpath, strerror(errno));
            fclose(src);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } else {
        dst = stdout;
    }

    char          *line = NULL;
    size_t         size = 0;
    unsigned long  linenum = 0;

    while (1) {
        ssize_t  len = getline(&line, &size, src);
        if (len < 0)
            break;

        linenum++;

        if (fwrite(line, 1, len, dst) != (size_t)len) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Write error on line %lu.\n", dstpath ? dstpath : "(standard output)", linenum);
            fclose(dst);
            fclose(src);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /* Technically, we don't need to release dynamically allocated (non-shared) memory,
       because we're just about to exit, and the OS will automagically do that for us.
       We can do this at any point we want during the loop, too. */
    free(line);
    line = NULL;
    size = 0;

    /* We do not know why getline() returned -1.  Check if an error occurred, and whether we're at end of input. */
    if (ferror(src) || !feof(src)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error on line %lu.\n", srcpath ? srcpath : "(standard input)", linenum);
        fclose(dst);
        fclose(src);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Check if any write errors have occurred. */
    if (ferror(dst)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Write error on line %lu.\n", dstpath ? dstpath : "(standard output)", linenum);
        fclose(dst);
        fclose(src);
    }

    /* Read errors should not occur at close time, but it costs very little for us to test anyway. */
    if (fclose(src)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Read error on line %lu.\n", srcpath ? srcpath : "(standard input)", linenum);
        fclose(dst);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Write errors can occur at close time, if the output has been buffered, or the target is on
       a remote filesystem.  Again, it costs us very little to check. */
    if (fclose(dst)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Write error on line %lu.\n", dstpath ? dstpath : "(standard output)", linenum);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* No errors; target is an identical copy of the source file. */
    fprintf(stderr, "%lu lines copied successfully.\n", linenum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The [SPDX-License-Identifier](https://spdx.org/licenses/) is a common way to indicate the license of the code.  I use CC0-1.0, which basically means *"use as you wish, just don't blame the author for any issues: no guarantees, no warranties."*

The `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` tells the GNU C library that we want it to expose POSIX.1-2008 features, which include `getline()`.  If you look at [man 3 getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), you'll see in the Synopsis section that glibc 2.10 and later require `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to be defined to at least `200809L`.

Most of the code is to print the usage, and getting the source and target file names from the command line, and handling `-` as a special name, "standard stream", so that it can be used even in pipes by specifying `-` as the input and/or output file name.

The `getline()` loop uses `fwrite()` to write the line to the target file.  This way, if the input contains embedded NUL bytes (`\0`), the target will still be identical to the source file.

After the loop, we discard the line buffer, although since the program is just about to exit, we could omit that (since the OS will release all dynamically allocated (non-shared) memory when we exit anyway).

I like code that checks with `ferror(src) || !feof(src)` if an error occurred in `src` or `src` did not reach end of input; and that checks the return value of `fclose()`, in case a delayed (write) error is reported.  Granted, `fclose()` should never fail for a read-only file, and `fclose()` should only fail for files we've written to in specific circumstances, but it costs very little to check, and this way the user running the program will be told if the program detected loss of data.

I believe it is morally reprehensible to ignore checking for such errors (especially "because they occur so rarely"), since such tests are the only way the human user can know whether the operation was successful, or if some odd problem occurred.  It is up to the human to investigate any problems, and up to our programs to report detectable issues.

Comment: There's no need for ant command-line inputs to this patricular program, so that part is a bit obsolete for me, but other than that you've showed some nice ideas, I'll give them a try! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `getline` function takes a `FILE *` as a parameter, not an `int`. Replace the following line:

```
int fd = open("./rules.txt", O_RDONLY);
```

By;

```
FILE *fin = fopen("./rules.txt", "r");
```

Fix the error checking in the following lines accordingly, like you did with `fout`.

Then replace the line:

```
int bytesRead = getline(&line, &len, fd);
```

Instead it should now use `fin`:

```
ssize_t bytesRead = getline(&line, &len, fin);
```

Note that `getline` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.
You are also never writing to `fout`, but I guess you're still working on this code.

Make sure to enable compiler warnings, because your compiler would surely have warned you for using an `int` parameter where a `FILE *` was expected.

Comment: I changed the code according to what you said and added write into fout with fprintf... I still get a segfault, what should I do?